Whatsapp API send document with message template
I'm trying to send a document with a template via the Whatsapp API.
I encounter a strange error in the API response which tells me that a parameter is missing even though it does not exist in the official documentation.
I get this error
{
    "error": {
        "message": "(#100) Invalid parameter",
        "type": "OAuthException",
        "code": 100,
        "error_data": {
            "messaging_product": "whatsapp",
            "details": "For component HEADER, parameter '' does not have a valid phone_number format. Length Limit is 20 characters and detailed format requirements can be found at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/cloud-api/guides/send-message-templates/utility-templates#template-parameters-and-restrictions."
        },
        "fbtrace_id": "AMpCyBYnc9ch7Ivdzk6sJ6S"
    }
}

Here my request body :
{
   "messaging_product":"whatsapp",
   "to":"{{Recipient-Number}}",
   "type":"template",
   "template":{
      "name":"docs",
      "language":{
         "code":"fr"
      },
      "components":[
         {
            "type":"header",
            "parameters":[
               {
                  "type":"document",
                  "document":{
                     "link":"https://pdfobject.com/pdf/sample.pdf"
                  }
               }
            ]
         },
         {
            "type":"body",
            "parameters":[
               {
                  "type":"text",
                  "text":"credit CS"
               },
               {
                  "type":"text",
                  "text":"Mutual"
               },
               {
                  "type":"text",
                  "text":"reçu"
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
}

